# Prove that ${f(x,y) = x^Txx^Tyy^Ty}$ is a valid kernel

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

The rules I can use without a proof are the following ones:
[image]

The thing that I know that a kernel is valid if it is symmetric, e.g. ${f(x,y) = f(y,x)}$ and if ${c^TKc >= 0}$, for each vector ${c \neq 0}$, but I don't know how to prove it, and don't know how to get the matrix K (if this is the correct way to solve this exercise).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\phi(\mathbf x)=\mathbf x\mathbf x^T\mathbf x$ be a nonlinear transformation for $\mathbf x$. Then, you can use the fourth rule in your screenshot, because $k(\mathbf x, \mathbf  y)=\phi(\mathbf x)^T\phi(\mathbf y)$ is a valid kernel since $k_3(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)=\mathbf x^T\mathbf y$ is a valid kernel.

Comment: But how do you know you have to start from a value ${\phi(x) = xx^Tx}$? By intuition?

Comment: @Ele975 Because you generally want to write  $\mathop{f}\left(x,y\right)$ as an inner product of the form $\langle \mathop{\phi}\left(x\right), \mathop{\phi}\left(y\right)\rangle$. Realizing that you have to take the transpose of $x^\top x x^\top$ to make it match the form of $y y^\top y$ is just a small step then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use R3 and get $xx^Tyy^T $and then mention that is $x^2y^2$